# Electron waves in atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics

In physics, the de Broglie equations tell us that things can matter behave both like a particle and like a wave and that its wavelength can be calculated by the de Broglie formula. So my question is then, do electrons "orbiting" a nucleus travel as a wave "around/orbit" this nucleus in a wave as well?

If so (since electrons are not a form of electromagnetic wave) through what medium are the electrons propagating as they orbit the nucleus as a wave? Also an added question: do electrons in the same orbital shell ever constructively or destructively interfere with other electrons with each other?

Comment: Have you tried looking through the website or searching the web in general?

Comment: +1. To me, this seems to be a reasonable question. I do not think answers are easily found on the internet.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2860/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135521/

Answer (score -1):

> So my question is then, do electrons "orbiting" a nucleus travel as a wave "around/orbit" this nucleus in a wave as well?

Both are nucleus and electrons waves, but you will see that the mass of the proton alone is 1,836.15267 times the mass of the electron.  The electron is a bound wave, represented by some wavefunction.

> If so (since electrons are not a form of EM wave) through what medium are the electrons propagating as they orbit the nucleus as a wave?

There is no medium except the electrons themselves, that is the change in ideology from the ether theories.

> Also an added question: Do electrons in the same orbital shell ever constructively or destructively interfere with other electrons with each other?

In a sense, but that is a bit of an oversimplification.  Using that language, the electrons actually interfere with themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your replies and welcome. However, I am still confused. (This stuff is kinda hard). I did try to look up stuff on the internet and it is because I looked up some stuff on the internet that I am kind of confused with the electron.

Comment: Thank you for your replies and welcome. However, I am still confused. (This stuff is kinda hard). I did try to look up stuff on the internet and it is because I looked up some stuff on the internet that I am kind of confused with the electron. According the basic definition of what a wave is that I looked on online. It said a wave is a transfer of energy and not mass itself. So I am still trying to wrap my head around the idea electrons orbits around the nucleus. So what is a bound wave & "represented by wavefunction" is that the same as an actual wave? If it is then what is being proporgated?

Comment: A wave is an amplitude oscillation.  For the electron, the oscillations are in the probability amplitude of the wavefunction.  What is being propagated is the electron itself.  Growing up only observing the classical world, the idea of matter being oscillatory is counter-intuitive, so don't be discouraged as you try to understand.

Comment: A wave function is not a probability amplitude.